# Text input value as a number

Tags: ruby

I want input field value to be a number instead of string.

A simple scenario is you have 2 input fields and submit button on a page. When you click submit you should get sum of numbers keyed in both the input fields and not appended strings.

I tried using "number_field_tag" for input type=number but the value is still a String and not Fixnum what I want.

Comment: parameter are always sent as string to server. Try using `.to_i` at the time you're adding the numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Surya stated in his comment, what comes from the form fields is always a string. But you can do something like this in the controller action that processes the form (presuming you're using Rails):

```
def process_form
  @result = params[:first_field].to_i + params[:second_field].to_i
end
```